# showing [0 Items] for s tag select in iPad

Tags: ipad, struts2

for iPad, the following code is showing [0 Items] in the initial of the form. But for the PC browser, it doesn't show anything.

[Edited]
And even though the list box have the data , the data are not showing in the list box in iPad too.

```
<s:select id="myList" name="myIds" list="myList" listKey="key" listValue="value" multiple="true" cssClass="selection-big" theme="simple" 
    onchange="detectChangeValue(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'a');"/>
```

How to make it not to show [ 0 Items ] and show the real list in the list box in iPad browser?

[Edited]
[image]

Comment: All s:select is producing is html, just post the resulting html.